# Repeat value with highland.js

Tags: javascript, highland.js

I need to create a stream which repeats some value. With bacon I can do this with [repeat primitive](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bacon-repeat)

Answer (score 1):

I finished with the code below:

```
const H = require('highland')

H((push, next) => {
  push(null, 'value to repeat')
  next()
})
```